# GREP create a list of words that contain a sting

Tags: grep

I have a folder with a lot of text files and would like to get a list of all words in that folder that contain a certain string. So, e.g. there is words in the form of 'IND:abc', 'IND:cde', ... and I am looking for a way to get a list of all words starting with IND:, so something like:

[IND:abc, IND:cde, IND:...]

Can grep do that?

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: Bee, Wesp and Bumblebee come to mind. How about Libelle, I think it has a sting, too.

Comment: @Ingo: Hilarious comment : Only after reading your comment I re-read the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -ho 'IND:\w\+' * | sort | uniq
```

`-h` suppresses the filenames so that you will only get the text. `-o` prints only the matching path of the text. If you want to see the duplicates just remove the `sort`, and `uniq`.